# VB.NET - How to delete multiple consecutive lines in a text file?

Tags: vb.net

I am making a customer management system for a school project and I need to be able to delete customers.
Each customer takes up 8 lines in the text file.

I have got it to delete one line using:

```
Dim lines() As String  
Dim outputlines As New List(Of String)  
Dim searchstring1 As String = lblName.Text  
lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Customers.text")  
For Each line As String In lines  
    If line.Contains(searchstring1) = False Then  
       outputlines.Add(line)  
       FileClose(1)  
       System.IO.File.Delete("Customers.text")  
       IO.File.WriteAllLines("Customers.text", outputlines)  
       FileClose(1)  
    End If  
Next
```

But I'm not sure how to repeat this another 7 times, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the for-each-loop, I would use a classical for-next, with a step of 8 - If we can be sure that each dataset consists of 8 lines, and the searchstring is found in the first:

```
...
For LineNo As Integer=0 to lines.count()-1 step 8
    If lines(LineNo).Contains(searchstring1) = False
        ...
    End If
Next lineNo
```

Additionally, you should close the input file directly after reading before going into the for-loop, and you should probably write the outputlines only after the for-next-loop is done, otherwise you will remove all customers after the searched one.

Next step is to check for errors which may occur during file operations...

Answer (score 0):

If your file has mixed format and cannot use `Step 8` because it not contains only N-8-rows of data, you can use a counter.
Set it to 8 when find customer and decrement it each loop.
The creation of new line in output file will be only when `counter = 0`.

```
Dim countMatchingLines As Integer = 0
For Each line As String In lines  
    If line.Contains(searchstring1) Then
        countMatchingLines = 8
    End If

    If countMatchingLines = 0 Then  
       outputlines.Add(line)  
       FileClose(1)  
       System.IO.File.Delete("Customers.text")  
       IO.File.WriteAllLines("Customers.text", outputlines)  
       FileClose(1)  
    Else
        countMatchingLines -= 1
    End If
Next
```

Another solution, is just skip next 8 lines by manipulation for-var-counter:

```
For i as Integer = 0 to lines.Count() - 1
    If line.Contains(searchstring1) Then
        i = Math.Min(i + 8, lines.Count()-1)
    Else
        outputlines.Add(line)  
        FileClose(1)  
        System.IO.File.Delete("Customers.text")  
        IO.File.WriteAllLines("Customers.text", outputlines)  
        FileClose(1)  
    End If
Next
```

It will avoid necessary iterates and Ifs..

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Text = RemoveParagraphOfText("GARBAGE RECORD", Line)
End Sub

Public Function RemoveParagraphOfText(ByVal textTobeRemoved As String, ByVal Message As String) As String
    RemoveParagraphOfText = Message.Replace(textTobeRemoved, "")
End Function
```